# How to disable expanding of schema for single schema in swagger?

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, drf-spectacular

I'm using `Django` with `DRF-Spectacular` and `swagger-ui`.

I'm interested in how can I disable expanding of Schema (only a single schema related to tokens) so it's only showing endpoint.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of what you are asking for? I.e. how the page looks now and where that part where you want to "disable expanding of schema for single schema" is located.

Answer (score 0):

To only show a subset of endpoints in the schema you have 2 options:

1. In `urls.py` use `SpectacularAPIView(urlconf=YOUR_SUBSET_OF_URLPATTERNS)`
2. Write a [preprocessing hook](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#step-7-preprocessing-hooks) that filters out endpoints that you don't want to expose.